# Android TextView start, top, end and bottom constants for Drawables array

Tags: android

The method [`TextView.getCompoundDrawablesRelative()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCompoundDrawables%28%29) returns an array of `Drawables` containing start, top, end and bottom compound drawables. Thus far I can't find any constants in the Android library that defines the index in the array where each compound drawable is stored. I do know from trial and error that index 1 of the array contains the top drawable.

Are there constants, that I may have overlooked, in the Android Library that define the index in the array returned by [`TextView.getCompoundDrawablesRelative()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCompoundDrawables%28%29) where each compound drawable is located? If so what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are just in the same order as [TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) (and the other similar methods):

> Index 0: left
>
> Index 1: top
>
> Index 2: right
>
> Index 3: bottom

Comment: That makes me a sad panda :,(